# Finding the root cause of Spanning-Tree recalculations (on Cisco Nexus 9000s)

Tags: cisco, spanning-tree, cisco-nexus

I have a nagging Rapid PVST problem on some Nexus 9000 switches.  Rapid-PVST keeps recalculating 3 to 5 times an hour.  We have in this topology (summarized):

```
  Edge Router                             Access Layer
+-------------+                         +-------------+
|             | Eth1/28         Eth1/54 |             |
| Nexus9000_1 +-------------------------+ Nexus9000_2 |
|             |         Vlan350         |             |
+-------------+       dot1q Trunk       +-------------+
                                               |Eth1/45 (dot1q trunk)
                                               |
                                      Something_Important
```

**SHOW OUTPUT: Nexus9000_1**

```
Nexus9000_1# sh spanning-tree vlan 350 detail | i from|topology|VLAN
 VLAN0350 is executing the rstp compatible Spanning Tree protocol
  Number of topology changes 1348 last change occurred 0:35:39 ago <---
          from Ethernet1/28                                        <---
  Times:  hold 1, topology change 35, notification 2
  Timers: hello 0, topology change 0, notification 0
  ... Output snipped ...
```

**SHOW OUTPUT: Nexus9000_2**

```
Nexus9000_2# sh spanning-tree vlan 350 detail | i from|topology|VLAN
 VLAN0350 is executing the rstp compatible Spanning Tree protocol
  Number of topology changes 1157 last change occurred 0:35:39 ago <---
          from Ethernet1/54                                        <---
  Times:  hold 1, topology change 35, notification 2
  Timers: hello 0, topology change 0, notification 0
  ... Output snipped ...
```

**BACKGROUND**

The reason I found the STP recalculations is because we got so many complaints about the device connected to Nexus9000_2 Eth1/45 having 30-ish second outages over and over again.  Configuring Nexus9000_2 Eth1/45 as `spanning-tree port type edge trunk` made the problem much less visible because STP moves into a forwarding state much faster with that port-type.

I checked and know that the interfaces in this diagram are not flapping.

**QUESTION**

Each of those switches says it received a [topology change notification (TCN)](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/spanning-tree-protocol/12013-17.html) from the other switch.  That's not very helpful... and I don't want to band-aid the problem with `spanning-tree port type edge trunk` on port Eth1/45.

*What is the best way to find the root cause of these STP topology changes using the tools available on Nexus 9000 switches?*

Please don't respond with `show spanning-tree internal event-history all` or other `show spanning-tree internal` commands without explaining what exactly to look for in those commands.

Comment: Do they actually _recalculate_ the spanning tree, or are they just flooding another switch's TC flagged BPDU? (while flushing their CAM tables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, I was able to solve the problem by turning on these debugs on Nexus9000_2:

- `debug spanning-tree rstp interface eth1/54`
- `debug spanning-tree event interface eth1/54`
- `debug spanning-tree bpdu_rx interface eth1/54`

The next time a BPDU triggered a calculation, the debug gave me detailed information on what was happening on the switchport.

The output of this command was also useful: `sh spanning-tree internal event-history all | begin VLAN0350`

Comment: Do tell what the ultimate problem was!

Comment: vpc `peer-switch` configured on a non-RPVST root switch